# docker-proxy is not in PATH

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

While running

> $ docker compose up --remove-orphans

I get the following error:

> Attaching to prometheus-dev,
> container123 Error response from daemon: driver failed programming
> external connectivity on endpoint prometheus-dev
> (91dea5a2f136f0b37e274640a0b9e6d417a5fdbbb3a9c948aa7c564ed70288da):
> Error starting userland proxy: error while starting docker-proxy:
> exec: "docker-proxy": executable file not found in $PATH error Command
> failed with exit code 1.

I installed `docker-for-linux` using `sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop-4.22.0-amd64.deb` on ubuntu.

What is the problem?

Comment: Hello, your issue looks similar to this one: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1627907. Can you run `systemctl show docker.service | grep ExecStart` to see if somehow the `--userland-proxy-path` arg is set?

Comment: It does not. the command does not return anything.

Comment: Hmm, nothing? Then, how is the docker daemon started?

Comment: idk but `docker exec -it alpine sh` works fine.

Comment: I guess you have the issue only when you're exposing ports. Can you try `docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 alpine`? Also, check how the docker daemon is started (`ps ax | grep dockerd`), and its configuration (could be `/etc/docker/daemon.json`).